# how to cancel sending a message from Outlook and close the form

Tags: c#, outlook

I try to cancel sending the message from Outlook. I need get all fields from mailItem and close it without sending.

in my code i get an error - Unable to execute command Item.Close during the event Item.Send.

```
public partial class MyMainForm
{
    Outlook.Application oApp;
    Outlook.MailItem mailItem;
    System.Threading.Timer timer_CloseMail;

  private void Mail_in_outlook()
    {
        oApp = new Outlook.Application();
        mailItem = Outlook.MailItem)oApp.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);

        TimerCallback tm = new TimerCallback(CloseMail);
        timer_CloseMail = new Timer(tm);

        oApp.ItemSend += oApp_ItemSend;
        mailItem.DeleteAfterSubmit = true;

        mailItem.Display(true);

        // get mailItem.HTMLBody and other field....

    }

void oApp_ItemSend(object Item,ref bool Cancel)
    {
        Cancel = true;
        MailtimeTimer.Change(0, 0);
    }

private void CloseMail(object sender)
    {
        mailItem.Close(Outlook.OlInspectorClose.olDiscard);
    }
```

Comment: @user3666197, don't [bold single words](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5699992).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some MAilItem methods (such as Send or Close) cannot be called in that event handler. You can use a timer (use the one from the Forms namespace since it runs on the same thread) and enable it in the ItemSEnd event. When the timer fires, disable it and call MailItem.Close - by that time you will be out o the ItemSent event.

Comment: i've try it. but timer event "tick" dosent fire even timeer.enabled = true;

Comment: mailitem is a local (to Mail_in_outlook) variable. How can you access it from timer_CloseMail_Tick? How do you initialize the timer_CloseMail variable?

Comment: Is that a GUI or console app?

Comment: it is GUI application.

Comment: Wait a sec: how can oApp_ItemSend event handler possibly fire if you set oApp variable to null? As soon as GC releases that object, it stops firing events.

Comment: mailItem.Display(true); - show mail form in dialog mode. oApp_ItemSend fire and cancel sending mail, but I can not close the window.

Comment: Are you sure timer_CloseMail is still alive by the time it is supposed to fire?